# OpenLayers2 - zoom to selected feature

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, zoom

If I have this vector layer:

```
var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector", {isBaseLayer: false});
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT(
                    "POLYGON ((-18 -3, -18 14, 15 14, 15 -3, -18 -3))"
                )
            );
vectors.addFeatures([feature]);
```

How I can zoom to a selected feature of the layer by a single click event?

Answer (score 9):

you can use it adding to any trigger:

```
var dataExtent = vectors.getDataExtent();
map.zoomToExtent(dataExtent);
```

briefly :

```
map.zoomToExtent(vectors.getDataExtent());
```

.

> getDataExtent
>
> ```
> getDataExtent: function ()
> ```
>
> Calculates the max extent which includes all of the features.

.

> zoomToExtent
>
> ```
> zoomToExtent: function(   bounds,
>   closest )
> ```
>
> Zoom to the passed in bounds, recenter

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I'm trying like this:`function zoomFunction(evt)
    {
        var dataExtent = vectors.features[i].geometry.getBounds();
        map.zoomToExtent(dataExtent, closest=true);        
    }

map.events.register("click", map, zoomFunction);` How can I get the feature order from the vectors?

Comment: what is that, i didnt understand? isnt it work? pls give some info...

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution:

```
function selected (evt) {
    map.zoomToExtent(evt.feature.geometry.getBounds(), closest=true);
}

vectors.events.register("featureselected", vectors, selected);

var control = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectors);

map.addControl(control);

control.activate();
```

Comment: you have expressed the question in wrong way. Your question must be "zoom to selected feature". i have gave you code about zooming to the layer.