# Zoom to a selected feature with Openlayers 2

Tags: openlayers-2

```
var cen = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lng,lat)
.transform(proj, map.getProjectionObject()); map.setCenter(cen,30);
```

I need to zoom into the feature selected.

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/24597/49538